# Can i use firebase realtime database locally? How?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use firebase realtime database   on my localhost without internet for my webapp.. I want to use it the same way we use mysql on localhost..

Comment: You can use it only locally just fine, but as soon as you go online, the data will be synced... (*As a side note, the answer which is marked as a duplicate, is not the same question*)

Comment: You can use Firebase Real-time Database Emulator though it's still on Beta as of today: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/test-rules-emulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database, and as such you must be online to use it.